# remove copies / fork in git history

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following git history, not really sure how i got there, but it seem i have a set of copies of D-G (git diff D D-copy is empty) which creates a fork in my git history, is there a way to fix this to remove the copies and create a history without the fork?

```
*   b4c394e (HEAD -> master, origin/master) I
|\
| * 17738ee G-copy
| * 6300744 F-copy
| * 62dbb41 E-copy
| * 951a5d9 D-copy
* | 05bfe4f H
* | 2701442 G
* | 242cf72 F
* | 2c9c7b6 E
* | b4bf474 D
|/
* 0f445d1 C
* ac8114f B
* 87759e6 A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `git reset HEAD~1` and now the history was clean again (no fork) with the changes from the last commit, which i added as a new commit and forced pushed. I did rename a remote repository recently, maybe that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following git history, not really sure how i got there ...

You got there, I predict / believe, by using `git rebase`—perhaps in the form of `git rebase -i` as in [karan dhillon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402591/1256452)—and then `git pull`.  Rebase by itself is fine, but you need to know what it does and some of its consequences.

> is there a way to fix this to remove the copies and create a history without the fork?

Yes, but there are some inconsequential, minor, or maybe fairly major, unpleasant consequences for *other people* in the process ... that is, *if* there are any other users of the `origin` repository involved.

The `rebase -i` method can work just fine (see [karan dhillon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402591/1256452) again), but considerably easier is a simple:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

(but first make sure, with `git status`, that you don't mind replacing all the files in your index and work-tree, i.e., that `git status` says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`).  Check the result with `git log` to make sure you like it.

The crucial step at the end, regardless of how you get the set of commits you want, is to use a variant of `git push --force` to update the *other* Git repository involved here.  That is, in the end, you *must* direct the other Git, the one over at origin, to discard some of *its* commits.  The fact that *your* Git has your `origin/master`—your copy of origin's `master`—means that at this point, they have all of these commits too (and maybe some more as well!).

If the Git repository over at whatever URL you have your Git remembering through the name `origin` is actively in use by others, you need to warn them whenever you force that shared Git repository to *lose* some commits.  If there are no other users of the other Git repository, e.g., if that's your own private GitHub copy, there is no one else you need to warn, so you're OK here.

Once you have the "right" history, you'll need to run:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

(which is relatively safe but you should still warn any other users) or:

```
git push --force origin master
```

(which is less-safe, especially if this is a shared repository over at origin).  The `-with-lease` variant uses your own Git's `origin/master`—its memory of *their* Git's `master`—to make sure their Git's `master` has not changed since you last had a chance to look things over and decided that yes, you really do want them to forget *their* commits.

#### Lots more detail

Let's look at the history here again:

```
*   b4c394e (HEAD -> master, origin/master) I
|\
| * 17738ee G-copy
| * 6300744 F-copy
| * 62dbb41 E-copy
| * 951a5d9 D-copy
* | 05bfe4f H
* | 2701442 G
* | 242cf72 F
* | 2c9c7b6 E
* | b4bf474 D
|/
* 0f445d1 C
* ac8114f B
* 87759e6 A
```

One of the nice properties of `git log --graph` is that it shows the first-vs-second parentage of commits by drawing the first parent as the direct vertical below—i.e., the *first* parent of `b4c394e` (the merge commit) is `05bfe4f` (commit `H`).  The *second* is `17738ee` (G-copy).

This indicates to me that you actually made, or had, commits `951a5d9` (which you call D-copy here), `62dbb41`, `6300744`, and `17738ee`—in that order—first, and either sent them to the other Git over at `origin` with `git push`, or got them from the other Git over at `origin`.

But there was probably something about original commit `D`, which you're calling `D-copy`, that you did not like.  Perhaps it was as simple as a typo in the commit message.  For whatever reason, you used a commit, probably `git rebase`, to tell *your* Git: *I don't like `951a5d9` then `62dbb41` then `6300744` then `17738ee`, I'd like instead to extract 951a5d9, change it a bit, and then make a new and improved copy.*

This new and improved copy turned out to be `b4bf474`: the commit you call `D` now.  Rebase automatically copies all subsequent commits, because it has to: the copy of the original `E-copy` that you call `E` has to use `b4bf474` as its parent, so it must be a copy with something changed.  The new commit winds up being `2c9c7b6`.  For the same reason, the commit you are calling F-copy has to be copied to the one you call F, and so on.  In the end, you have four new-and-improved commits, in sequence, starting with `b4bf474` and ending with `2701442`.

None of these new-and-improved copies exist in the other Git repository over at `origin`.  It still has `17738ee` as its last `master` commit.  Your own Git has thrown out your originals (the one you're calling copies) because the new and improved copies (the ones you're calling originals) are, well, new-and-improved.

Then, you made commit `H`, which is all-new.  Then you went to send your new commits—the new and improved ones followed by the all-new one—to the Git over at `origin`, with `git push origin master`.  But for whatever reason, you ran `git pull` before your `git push origin master` succeeded.

(If you ran `git push origin master` *before* you ran `git pull`, the other Git, over at `origin`, said no.  More specifically, your Git sent them the five new commits, `D`-through-`H`, and asked them to change their name `master` to remember `H` as the last commit on *their* branch.  They noticed that this would discard `D-copy`-through-`G-copy`.  They therefore said *no, I'd lose some commits*, which comes through as a `rejected (non-fast-forward)` error message, along with a hint suggesting that you use `git pull`.)

Unfortunately, what `git pull` means is *run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` based on what the fetch saw*.  The fetch obtained their `master`, which still identified commit `17738ee` at this time.  Your Git then did:

```
git merge -m "merge branch master of <url>" 17738ee
```

(more or less), which created the merge commit `b4c394e` (commit `I`) that you see at the top of your `git log` output.  That commit combined (merged) commits `05bfe4f` and `17738ee`.  Then you ran:

```
git push origin master
```

This time, you sent them the commits up through and including `I` (not just `H`) that they did not already have, and asked them to set their `master` to point to commit `I`.  That was OK with them: that did *not* lose commit `17738ee`, because starting at `b4c394e` and working backwards, they can still find commit `17738ee`: it's the second parent of `b4c394e`.

What you will end up doing, however you do it, is to create some string of commits that ends at commit `H`—i.e., the same hash ID you have now—or some new-and-improved copy of commit `H` (i.e., some different hash ID: the hash ID is the *real* name of the commit; the subject and message are just data within the actual commit).  You will then have your branch name `master` point to (store the hash ID of) this last commit.  The commit itself stores the hash ID of the previous commit that is also to be considered contained in the `master` branch.  The previous commit contains the hash ID of the next commit back, and so on.

Once your `master` has the right hash ID, you will use `git push` to send any new commits, that you have but they don't, to the other Git over at the URL stored under the name `origin`.  That string of commits ends at commit `05bfe4f` or its new-and-improved replacement.  You then need to *order* them—not just ask them politely—to set *their* `master` to hold the same hash ID that *your* `master` holds.  That's the `git push --force` step.

If you use the simple (and much older) `git push --force`, your Git just sends a command: *set your `master`!*  If you use the newer (but by now very standard) `git push --force-with-lease`, your Git sends a more complicated command: *I think your `master` is ______.  If so, set your master to _____ instead.  Tell me whether you update your `master`.*  Your Git fills in these blanks with the appropriate hash IDs.

Their Git then obeys, or doesn't, and sends your Git the result.  Your Git then either tells you that the push succeeded, and updates your `origin/master`, or tells you that it failed, and doesn't.  If it was because the hashes didn't match up, their `master` has changed and you should run `git fetch` to update your `origin/master`, and then see what the heck is going on.

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` removes the latest git commit

Comment: @Erlend: yes, and the latest—perhaps better to say the *last* on the branch—is the merge. The `~1` means *first parent* so if the current branch name `master` currently names `b4c394e` and its first parent is `05bfe4f`, this sets `master` to name `05bfe4f` instead: and now the history starting from `master` is commit `05bfe4f` on back.

Comment: The key here is that Git *access* commits by hash ID. It *finds* one specific commit—the last one contained in some branch—by reading a *branch name*, and then it works backwards from there, because every commit holds the raw hash ID of its predecessor or *parent* commit. So we force the name `master` to back up once, for this particular setup.

Comment: Git can, at this point, still find the merge commit because your name `origin/master` identifies it. (On the other Git, over on the origin system, *their* name `master` still identifies that merge commit, too, and your `origin/master`, which your Git sets based on their `master` every time you update, remembers the same hash ID in your own repository.)

Comment: I just want to remove the copies and rebase so i don’t have a fork.

Comment: I am the only user and have nothing to commit. I have diffed all the copies and there is nothing changed there. I’m having trouble keeping up with your explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in console:

```
git rebase -i head~6
```

Then simply put delete or remove all those commits and save by typing:

```
:wq
```

Comment: i tried that and lost the latest commit b4c394e I (i have backup..), which did not show up in when i do rebase -i

Comment: Did you push these changes to remote?

Comment: no only local, i dont want to push anything until im happy with the local git history

Comment: ok do a git pull so that your local is restored again. Then try the rebase command again but this time dont delete your latest commit

Comment: but the last one is one of the copies..? i tried not to but then i get a conflict